# Most popular pairs of shops for workers from each company

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I've got 2 tables, one with sales and one with companies:

Sales Table

```
Transaction_Id   Shop_id     Sale_date    Client_ID
```

```
92356            24234       11.09.2018    12356
92345            32121       11.09.2018    32121
94323            24321       11.09.2018    21231
94278            45321       11.09.2018    42123
```

Company table

```
Client_ID  Company_name
```

```
12345      ABC 
13322      ABC  
32321      BCD
22221      BCD
```

What I want to achieve is distinct count of Clients from each Company for each pair of shops(Clients who had at least 1 transaction in both of shops)  :

```
Shop_Id_1     Shop_id_2   Company_name    Count(distinct Client_id)
```

```
12356         12345       ABC             31
12345         14278       ABC             23
14323         12345       BCD             32
14278         12345       BCD             43
```

I think that I have to use self join, but my queries even with filter for one week is killing DB, any thoughts on that? I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2012.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried exactly? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: Also, those Shop_Id_1 and 2 don't appear correct. You don't have those shop id's in your data, should that be the client id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a self-join and aggregation, with a twist.  The twist is that you want to include the company in each `sales` record, so it can be used in the self-join:

```
with sc as (
      select s.*, c.company_name
      from sales s join
           companies c
           on s.client_id = c.client_id
     )
select sc1.shop_id, sc2.shop_id, sc1.company_name, count(distinct sc1.client_id)
from sc sc1 join
     sc sc2
     on sc1.client_id = sc2.client_id and
        sc1.company_name = sc2.company_name
group by sc1.shop_id, sc2.shop_id, sc1.company_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some issues with your question. I interpreted it as such that the company table contains the shop ID's, not the ClienId's.

First you can create a solution to get the shops as rows for each company. Here I chose a maximum of 5 shops per company. Don't forget the semicolon in the previous statement before the cte's.

```
WITH CTE_Comp AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY ShopID) AS RowNumb 
    FROM Company AS C
)

SELECT C1.ShopID, 
      C2.ShopID AS ShopID_2, 
      C3.ShopID AS ShopID_3, 
      C4.ShopID AS ShopID_4, 
      C5.ShopID AS ShopID_5, 
      C1.CompanyName
INTO ShopsByCompany
FROM CTE_Comp AS C1
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Comp AS C2 ON C1.CompanyName= C2.CompanyName AND RowNumb = 2 
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Comp AS C2 ON C1.CompanyName= C3.CompanyName AND RowNumb = 3 
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Comp AS C2 ON C1.CompanyName= C4.CompanyName AND RowNumb = 4 
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Comp AS C2 ON C1.CompanyName= C5.CompanyName AND RowNumb = 5 
WHERE C1.RowNumb = 1
```

After that, in a few steps, I think you could get the desired result:

```
WITH ClientsPerShop AS 

(
    SELECT ShopID,
         COUNT (DISTINCT ClientID) AS TotalClients
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY ShopID
)

, ClienstsPerCompany AS 

(
    SELECT CompanyName,
         SUM (TotalClients) AS ClientsPerComp
    FROM Company AS C
    INNER JOIN ClientsPerShop AS CPS ON C.ShopID = CPS.ShopID
    GROUP BY CompanyName
)

SELECT * 
FROM ClienstsPerCompany AS CPA
INNER JOIN ShopsByCompany AS SBC ON SBC.CompanyName = CPA.CompanyName
```

Hopefully this will bring you closer to your solution, best of luck!